# Ansible - Extract record from dict on value

Tags: ansible

In ansible, I've got a a list of dict like:

```
- { name: "a" }
- { name: "b", cond: true }
```

I would like to extract the list of name when cond is not defined or false (1) and also a list when cond is true or not defined (2):

```
1 => [ 'a' ]
2 => [ 'a', 'b' ]
```

How to do that? I did not find.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that with the `json_query` filter:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    mylist:
      - name: a
      - name: b
        cond: true

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        true_or_unset: "{{ mylist|json_query('[?cond == null || cond].[name]') }}"
        false_or_unset: "{{ mylist|json_query('[?cond == null || !cond].[name]') }}"

    - debug:
        msg:
          true_or_unset: "{{ true_or_unset }}"
          false_or_unset: "{{ false_or_unset }}"
```

Which produces:

```
PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "false_or_unset": [
            [
                "a"
            ]
        ], 
        "true_or_unset": [
            [
                "a"
            ], 
            [
                "b"
            ]
        ]
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: Thanks, It is exactly what I was looking for!